# Navigating in Z-Order curve with different ordering

Tags: tiling

I want to navigate in a Z-order curve by moving up, down, left or right.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) has this section :

> This property can be used to offset a Z-value, for example in two dimensions the coordinates to the top (decreasing y), bottom (increasing y), left (decreasing x) and right (increasing x) from the current Z-value z are:

```
top    = (((z & 0b10101010) − 1) & 0b10101010) | (z & 0b01010101)
bottom = (((z | 0b01010101) + 1) & 0b10101010) | (z & 0b01010101)
left   = (((z & 0b01010101) − 1) & 0b01010101) | (z & 0b10101010)
right  = (((z | 0b10101010) + 1) & 0b01010101) | (z & 0b10101010)
```

However this page describes the Z order as being :

```
0|1
---
2|3
```

My curve however has order :

```
2|3
---
0|1
```

and has 14 levels max (i.e. in base 4 the identifier of a location is maximum 14 digits long, so 28 bits).

How to adapt these formulas ? Simply calling "top" "bottom" and vice versa doesn't work.

EDIT : never mind, this is exactly what you should do, it was a typo on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call "top" "bottom" and vice versa.